# Apache localhost not responding to clients until reset

Tags: php, apache

I have setup a local server on a regular desktop (not a server desktop) and have 3-4 client machines accessing the local web application I developed from the server via a WIFI router (server is connected to router via cable. All clients via WIFI).

When two of the clients are connected to the application all is well, but when a third (or more) machine joins in there are periods where each machine does not get any service from the server (the application webpage remains loading until I manually reset Apache on the server via services). At times the server responds when one of the clients refresh their page but most of the time I have to perform a reset of the Apache server.

This occurs roughly once an hour on average (6 hours of continuous usage) as the clients are using the application.

Server is running Windows 7 and Apache v2.4 with PHP v5.4

Server and all client machines are running AVG internet security

Firewall is handled by AVG Internet Security

Is this issue due to the code in my application, desktop not being able to manage requests like a server machine, antivirus or a mix of the three?
If so, how can I set-up the server to reset automatically?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

It is a application where users write reports on files after reviewing information

-Frequent sql requests for file data

-No images

-Some pages contain multiple sql queries that represent the page content

-Network has no internet connection

-Code does not make requests for external information from the internet

-All client machines run the application on Google Chrome web browser

Answer (score 0):

But it rarely happens but sometimes the amount of connection is restricted by the third-party interface being used by the application. We are unable to figure out the reason unless having more details like what content of your app, and the error code apache or HTTP returning.

Comment: Whenever the server fails to serve clients (endless page loading) once I reset the apache service they get a 'this site cannot be reached' message. I will update above with app content summary

Comment: When the issue happens again, following steps to figure the issue: 1. Check if your apache is working fine, you can visit other static pages on the server or telnet your web service (Exp: telnet 192.168.0.1 80) to check if caused by network issue; 2. Check if your Apache and PHP log have useful information; 3: Check the status of your database with DB tool; 4: Check if there is any relative zombie process staying in the task manager on the server, if yes, kill one and try accessing again.

Comment: All server settings seem to work fine. Perhaps it may be related to my PHP code. Let me be 100% sure that though by running though each code block

Answer (score 0):

This kind of situations is difficult to track, especially on Windows where diagnostic tools aren't as readily available as on other platforms.

I suppose you can try and check the antivirus by either running server and clients with no antivirus at all for some hours, or disabling and re-enabling the antivirus when the hangup occurs.

Apart from that, you would need to pinpoint where the error occurs:

- in the connection stage (Windows OS is the problem)
- in the response stage (Apache is the problem - try fiddling with the child spawning parameters)
- in the management stage (PHP is the problem - you can probably check this by changing the setup from PHP-as-a-module, and PHP-as-CGI-application)
- in the response stage (that is, connection to the SQL server). You can check this by setting up some pages that use different combinations of session, database, and output buffering and see whether *those* pages remain reachable even when the application is hung up.

For an example of the last, if a page such as

```
<?php print date("H:i:s"); phpinfo(); ?>
```

remains reachable and correctly refreshes (that's why the date() command) even when the app does not respond, this demonstrates that Windows, Apache and PHP are "innocent", and either the SQL server has issues, or you do not interface with it correctly. It might be for example be the case (though unlikely in this instance) that the resident PHP module is accumulating connections to the SQL server and not releasing them, so that after a while you need to stop Apache (thereby freeing the module) and restart.

If this were the case, even if it's not a "real" fix, you can set up Apache so that all children die and are replaced after a small number of requests (once it was 150, but when leaks all but disappeared, I believe that the default became 0 -- Apache children no longer die. Check it out, I might well misremember).

Comment: I will perform these checks and report. I have also identified a possible source being the Google chrome browser (https://www.wintips.org/fix-google-chrome-blank-page-problem/). I will run the application on firefox when the server fails to serve and see what occurs